# How to calculate Standard Deviation using loops on Python

Tags: for-loop, standards, python-3.3, standard-deviation

I have to calculate the standard deviation using loops for a list. 
This is what I have:

```
elif user_option == 2:
  stdev= 0
  average = 0
  for val in scores_list:
    diffsquared= (val - average)**2
    sum_diffsquared= diffsquared + val
    stdev= ((sum_diffsquared)/num_scores)**(1/2)
    print(stdev)
```

I keep on getting the wrong number.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems in your code.  First, "sum_diffsquared" is being calculated outside of the loop.  Secondly, you declare the average as 0.  You need to calculate the average first.

```
import numpy
import scipy

stddev = 0
average = 0
scores = [0,1,2,3,4]
average = numpy.mean(scores) #or calculate it yourself
diffsquared = 0
sum_diffsquared = 0
for val in scores:
  diffsquared = (val-average)**2
  sum_diffsquared = diffsquared + sum_diffsquared
stddev = ((sum_diffsquared)/len(scores))**(1/2) # corrected
print(stddev)
print(numpy.sqrt(numpy.var(scores)))
```

The output is:

```
1.41421356237
1.41421356237
```

Showing that the calculation is now correct.

Comment: What I did is I calculated the average in an elif statement before this elif statement. But for some reason it says that "average" is not defined

Comment: You must calculate the average before the corresponding 'if' statement.  You should familiarize yourself with the concept of variable scopes ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science) ).  In short, your variable "average" is undefined for that 'elif' scope.  If you declare "average" before your 'if/elif' statements, the variable will still be visible through all 'if/elif' scopes.